# Regular expression negation in R

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

I have a problem trying to find a way to implement negation in R regular expressions.

```
my_strings <- c("a non-rheumatic fever", "a nonrheumatic fever", "a rheumatic fever", "a not rheumatic fever")
my_strings
## [1] "a non-rheumatic fever" "a nonrheumatic fever" "a rheumatic fever" "a not rheumatic fever"
```

In the above string, I'm trying to find a regular expression that will output just the following:

```
## [1] "a rheumatic fever"
```

I've tried the following but I can't figure out how to negate the presence of `"no(n|t)(\\s+|-)?"` immediately preceding `"rheumatic"`:

```
t_inc <- "\\b([^n][^o][^nt](\\s+|-)?(rheumatic))\\b"
grep(t_inc, my_strings, ignore.case = T, perl = T, value = T)
## character(0)

t_inc <- "\\b([^(no(n|t))](\\s+|-)?(rheumatic))\\b"
grep(t_inc, my_strings, ignore.case = T, perl = T, value = T)
## character(0)
```

Please could someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be we can modify the syntax to a bit simpler one by making ue of `invert` as mentioned by @IceCreamToucan in the comments

```
grep("no[nt][- ]?rheumatic", my_strings, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "a rheumatic fever"
```

the pattern matches 'no', followed by either letter 'n' or t', followed by a - or space if present and the word 'rheumatic'.  With `invert= TRUE`, it will return all those matches that are not matching with the pattern

Comment: Thank you. I was initially trying to identify "rheumatic" as part of a larger list of exclusion terms, but I guess I'll have to identify it separately from this.